# The site turned orange

Tags: support, bug

All text on the site is suddenly orange. Unfortunately, orange on white isn't readable by humans. I don't know if this is a bug or another "brilliant" UI redesign. I can't change theme below "Flair" in settings - they all look the same suddenly - so I'm assuming it's a bug.

Only the main scifi site is affected, not meta, nor other SE sites.

How do I turn the site readable again?

Comment: It’s a bug and being looked at, should be fixed soon.

Comment: Either that or my getting elected broke something. Take your pick.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Carrot-theme... gah, now I reject voting for you :) Anyway if you have it confirmed by some CM that it's a bug maybe post it as answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: On the plus side, now that they've forced everyone to have the same site theming, this balls-up has been transmitted to pretty much every site *with just a single button push*, instead of requiring them to individually muck up every site one after another. I call that progress, of a sort.

Comment: @Valorum They didn't push the big orange button on the control panel saying "DO NOT PUSH", did they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s a bug and is getting fixed now. See [the main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367643/345161) on it:

> A fix is getting deployed now. We’ve got a new [theming API in Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/theming/) that was leaking a bit. Funnily enough, all the themes we happened to test via smoke tests already had orange buttons so we didn't catch it.
>
> And before everyone shouts about visual regression testing, yeah. I agree. We're working on that too